# Getting an in-memory representation of the JPEG rendering of an Image

Tags: java, image, arrays

I need to know how to get an array of bytes from a loaded image, in java. BufferedImage seems not to supply any methods that produce an array of bytes, so what do I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage; //assumed that you have created it already
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"jpg", byteStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteStream.toByteArray();
```